# Copiar un worksheet de un archivo de excel a otro

Tags: python, excel, archivo

Hola buenos días tengo el siguiente código.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import Workbook

wP =load_workbook(r'C:\Users\Arrontec\Desktop\Automatizacion\Request1_2.xlsx')
wB =load_workbook(r'C:\Users\Arrontec\Desktop\Automatizacion\Request1_1.xlsx')

wPs = wP.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
wBs = wB.get_sheet_by_name('here')

counter = 0
new_rows = []
for rrow in wPs.iter_rows():
    new_rows.append([])
    for cell in rrow:
        new_rows[counter].append(cell.value)
    counter +=1
for wrow in new_rows:
    wBs.append(wrow)

wB.save('Request1_1.xlsx')
```

Pero en este caso, al usar append lo agrega al final, como podría agregarlo al inicio del archivo.

Agredeceria muchísimo la ayuda, o alguna idea que me podrían dar. Llevo algún tiempo con este problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de editar la pregunta lo que querias era copiar los datos de una hoja a otra, sustituyendo las celdas correspondientes y dejando el resto sin modificar (una especie de actualización de **parte** de una hoja con datos de otra). Si sigues queriendo hacer esto puedes hacerlo iterando sobre cada celda de la hoja origen y sustituyendo el valor de la celda correspondiente en la hoja destino usando las coordenadas de cada celda de origen:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook


wP =load_workbook(r'C:\Users\Arrontec\Desktop\Automatizacion\Request1_2.xlsx')
wB =load_workbook(r'C:\Users\Arrontec\Desktop\Automatizacion\Request1_1.xlsx')

wPs = wP.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
wBs = wB.get_sheet_by_name('here')

for rrow in wPs.iter_rows():
    for cell in rrow:
        wBs[cell.coordinate] = cell.value

wB.save('Request1_1a.xlsx')
```

Comment: Exactamente eso era lo que necesitaba. Muchisimas gracias